# Sending Batches Interview Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have encountered the following interview question from another website:

> You are given a bunch of emails in an inbox. You want to send all the
>   sender addresses to some server. You can send them in batches (each
>   batch containing a bunch of sender email addresses). The restriction
>   is that no batch can contain duplicate email address. How would you
>   write a program to send all the email addresses in batches such that
>   it takes the minimum number of batches.
>
> Analyze the complexity

The answer to this that I like involves placing the emails into a binary search tree (thus removing the duplicates), then serializing it and sending it. This would send just one batch, and is O(n*log n) time. Anyone care to chime in with a better solution?

Comment: the complexity of what you suggested is N*log(N), almost everything involving sorting is N*log(N)

Comment: can the same address be sent multiple times in different batches?

Comment: @bobah I don't think so.

Comment: Ther's no detail about the addresses and I'm not expecting those to be ordered in any way. If you are looking for a duplicate in a "not ordered set" you cannot obtain better result than n*log(n). Bobah is right

Comment: Is the solution I gave n*log(n) because that's the time complexity of creating a binary search tree from an unordered set?

Comment: @JohnRoberts - correct, because of the binary search tree, N*log(N) + N ~ N*log(N)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use hash, first you check if special name is in hash, if not, you will put it hash and add it to batch. this is O(n) in average, but your current method is O(n logn).

Your current approach is O(n log n) because creating binary tree takes O(n logn), as you any comparison base algorithm, fails to bit `n log n` barrier.

Also about the hash function, it takes O(n) in average. In all it's better than sorting methods in speed, but it takes may be too much space, and you should consider your data format.

Comment: I like your solution. Would you care to explain why mine is O(n*log(n))? - I don't quite understand why.

Comment: @JohnRoberts, I'll explain 30 min later.

Comment: worst case estimate (very improbable but theoretically correct) for hash based algorithms is N**2 (case when all e-mail addresses end up in the same bucket).

Comment: @bobah So that worst case estimate includes O(N) time for insertion into the hash table, and O(N^2) for searches?

Comment: @JohnRoberts, worst case is not O(n^2) is still O(n log n), because normally in advanced algorithms you can use advance hash tables which are fast even in worst case, also worst case occurs during insertion.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about why your algorithm is at worst n*log(n)?

Comment: @JohnRoberts, If you check the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), in this page different hashing functions are discussed, they said in the worst case it takes O(1) time for basic operation in many cases, but actually this is not O(1) it's O(log something), but for simplicity (I guess), they mentioned it's O(1), actually this order is depends to too many things and most important thing is computation model, and size of input data, ...

Comment: So if we assume insertions are constant time, then in worst case (every address is unique), we will have O(N) time, correct? And since we have to also check if each value is in the hash (and according to the Wiki page, search is worse case O(N)), won't we have O(N^2) for the searching part? So, O(N) + O(N^2) ~ O(N^2)?

Comment: @JohnRoberts, No lookup in good hash table is not O(n), it's around O(1), see for example [Cuckoo hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Cuckoo_hashing).